# [Python+Bokeh]: how to make a needle dial?

Tags: python, bokeh

I need a needle dial, showing a real time value. This value changes the needle angle, not position.

Up to now all I could do is to use a **ray()** or **annular_wedge()** glyph, but this solution has a number of problems: previous lines are not deleted, after a few updates it freezes, artifacts. Completely unusable.

This is the stripped down code I am working on at the moment.

```
from bokeh.driving import linear
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
import random

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
       x_range=[0, 2], y_range=[0, 2],
       x_axis_type=None, y_axis_type=None)

@linear()
def update(step):
    ref_angle = random.random() * 2 * 3.14
    p.ray(x=[1], y=[1], length=0.5, angle=ref_angle, color="red", line_width=2)

curdoc().add_root(p)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 1000)
```

As you can see I need to rotate the ray updating **ref_angle**.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of drawing a new ray on each update, you could make a `ColumnDataSource` object containing the ref_angle data, and then update that data.

The following code should just work if you have a bokeh server running already (in a different terminal run `bokeh serve`).

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.client import push_session
import random

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           x_range=[0, 2], y_range=[0, 2],
           x_axis_type=None, y_axis_type=None)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(ref_angle=[0]))
p.ray(x=1, y=1, length=0.5, angle='ref_angle', color="red",
      line_width=2, source=source)

# open a session to keep our local document in sync with server
session = push_session(curdoc())

def update():
    source.data.update(ref_angle=[random.random() * 2 * 3.14])

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 1000)

session.show(p)  # open the document in a browser
session.loop_until_closed()  # run forever
```

Comment: Thank you jsignell! 
Your solution is pretty straightforward and very reasonable.
Thank you also for the time you dedicated to write down a working code.